# Different messages written to catalina.out

Tags: java, tomcat

What are the various messages written to catalina.out? I understand tomcat's internal logging messages land here, but I also see some INFO messages. Why are logging messages typically of log4j logging in catalina.out? What other messages are written to this file?

Answer (score 0):

If your log4j logger is configured also to send logs to CONSOLE (understood as stdout), that's the reason, why you see those entries in catalina.out. In simple words: what goes into System.out, goes into catalina.out.

Comment: When you say send logs to CONSOLE, do you mean having the ConsoleHandler set? I don't have a single System.out.println in my application code btw.

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: Yes, any handler, that writes to stdout (I don't remember the exact name of this handler class --- it might by `ConsoleHandler` as you say). What is this INFO message about? It does it come from your code? Or maybe it's from log4j itself (like info about not correctly configured loggers --- but I believe it would be WARN then)?

Comment: That is exactly my question. Why are INFO messages being written to catalina.out?

Comment: I asked *what* is being logged, not *why*. 8) Maybe we could find out from the message where does it come from. Can you provide the message and possibly your log4j.(properties|xml) config file?